# Box-Shadow Transition Not Smooth in Chrome Browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, box-shadow

Strange stutter/choppy transition on box-shadow using Chrome browser. Haven't noticed this before. Firefox, IE, Opera execute transition as expected. Any one have the same experience and possibly a solution?

```css
html {
  text-align: center;
  font: 13px Open Sans;
  color: #5c5c5c
}

a,
input,
button {
display:inline-block;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  border: 4px solid #dedede;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  line-height:1;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow .5s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
  -moz-transition: box-shadow .5s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
  transition: box-shadow .5s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
}

a:hover,
input:hover,
button:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 4px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
}
```

```html
<h1>I AM AN INPUT</h1>
<p>For some reason unknown to myself, a box-shadow transition<br>on HOVER, executes choppy (stutters). Only experiencing in Chrome so far.</p>
<input type="submit" value="Input">
<a href="#">Fine on Link</a>
<button name="button">
Fine on Button
</button>
```

Comment: Box-shadow is one of the choppier effects to render.  If you only have issue on 'input type=submit', perhaps you can drop that dinosaur code. :)

Comment: Tried on Chrome 58 in Mac 10.12 and cannot reproduce your problem. The box-shadow transition seems perfect.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle - Wish I could but ecomm platform I work under uses it for panel updates (forms). At shaochuancs - I'm on Windows 7 and 10